# PHP Wordpress quotes issue

Tags: php, wordpress

Having a quotes issue, need a second pair of eyes!

```
echo "<img src='" . bloginfo('template_url') . "img/" . $f['mainImage'] . ".png' />";
```

Using the Wordpress function bloginfo to get the theme path!

All i'm getting is the path printed out on the page, no image!

Thanks

What is output:

```
 http://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/themes/example
<img src="/img/digital.png">
```

Comment: When you view source, what exactly is printed to the page

Comment: Is it possible that the function `bloginfo()` performs its own `echo`?

Comment: @jnpcl, good point, what would i do then?

Comment: You can use get_bloginfo() instead as I stated below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `bloginfo()` performs its own echo.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo

In your situation, you would use this code:

```
echo "<img src='"; bloginfo('template_url'); echo "img/" . $f['mainImage'] . ".png' />";
```

Answer (score 2):

`bloginfo()` is only used to directly output the requested value. Use [`get_bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) instead to work with the value before echo'ing it.

```
echo sprintf(
    '<img src="%s/img/%s.png" />', 
    get_bloginfo('template_url'), 
    $f['mainImage']
);
```

Comment: Yeah this looks cool! Both great answers and technically both worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As jnpcl has surmised, it looks like `bloginfo()` is print out the data for you.

You've got two options:

- use the `get_bloginfo()` function, which wont just print it out but return it instead
- Take that into account, echo part of the image tag, call the function, echo the rest